# Updating column in another table with combined columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have two tables: surveys and survey_ids, where I'm essentially migrating some of the data from survey_ids into surveys.

'surveys' has one column called dist_string which should ideally be the combination of the columns 'dist_admin' and 'dist_user' in survey_ids.

I wanted to do an update on surveys.dist_string (which is currently '' for all records) while concurrently merging the two columns survey_ids.dist_admin and survey_ids.dist_user together into surveys.dist_string, but I've been a little stuck. I have other columns in the surveys table with a not null constraint, so I run into problems if I were to try an insert into for dist_string. There's data already in the other columns, inserted from survey_ids.

From survey_ids:

```
 dist_admin    | dist_user
 --------------+--------------
               | 456dfghjk46
  0987ghasdf7  |
               | 123ghjwe46c
               | 5thw67de523
  4r5thgffghk  | 
  2qrt75434th  | 
               | 876tjheg3wg
  9uh7ygwedf6  |
```

I want dist_string from surveys to look like

```
  dist_string   
 -------------
  456dfghjk46   
  0987ghasdf7
  123ghjwe46c
  5thw67de523 
  4r5thgffghk
  2qrt75434th
  876tjheg3wg 
  9uh7ygwedf6
```

How do I accomplish this?

Edit: @coalesce, when I do that, I get for dist_string:

```
  dist_string   
 -------------

  0987ghasdf7


  4r5thgffghk
  2qrt75434th

  9uh7ygwedf6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

```
SELECT * FROM survey_ids;
┌────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ id │ dist_admin │ dist_user │
├────┼────────────┼───────────┤
│  1 │ (null)     │ ab1       │
│  2 │ cd2        │ (null)    │
└────┴────────────┴───────────┘
(2 rows)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM surveys;          
┌────┬─────────────┐
│ id │ dist_string │
├────┼─────────────┤
│  1 │             │
│  2 │             │
└────┴─────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Running

```
UPDATE surveys
SET dist_string = COALESCE(dist_admin, dist_user)
  FROM survey_ids
  WHERE surveys.id = survey_ids.id
;
```

Will update `surveys` to :

```
SELECT * FROM surveys;
┌────┬─────────────┐
│ id │ dist_string │
├────┼─────────────┤
│  1 │ ab1         │
│  2 │ cd2         │
└────┴─────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

---

In case the values are not `NULL` be the empty string, use :

```
UPDATE surveys   
SET dist_string = CASE WHEN dist_user = '' THEN dist_admin ELSE dist_user END
  FROM survey_ids
  WHERE surveys.id = survey_ids.id
;
```

or, mixing both (in case you have empty strings and `NULL`s) :

```
UPDATE surveys   
SET dist_string = CASE 
                    WHEN dist_user = '' THEN dist_admin
                    WHEN dist_admin = '' THEN dist_user
                    ELSE COALESCE(dist_admin, dist_user)
                  END
  FROM survey_ids
  WHERE surveys.id = survey_ids.id
;
```

Comment: Wrote this above, but I'll write it here:

 notice my surveys table populates dist_string with only dist_admin in the places where dist_admin record has been populated. The records that have dist_user is null in dist_string  Why could that be?

Comment: `COALESCE` uses the second value if the first one is `NULL`. If the second one is `NULL` it will return `NULL`, or if the first one is not `NULL` but (for instance) the empty string, than it will use that one.

Comment: I just notice your question says 'merge the two' but your example seem to indicate 'take the one that is not null/empty'. Which one is it ?

Comment: That makes sense, but dist_string now only has records for dist_admin in the places where dist_admin was not null in survey_ids. When I do a coalesce without an insert, I see that it does as intended (based on your comment here), but it doesn't do that in the case of updating surveys. It's assuming since dist_admin is null, then the dist_string should be null and doesn't update with dist_user.

I want to take the one that is not null/empty.

Comment: The only possible reason I can think of is that the tables contain empty string instead of `Null`s. If you're running `psql`, could you enter `\pset null '<<NULL>>'` (to display `null` instead of blanks) and rerun the queries ?

Comment: I did that, realized none of them are null, just ''.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**COALESCE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html) to select the non-null value of the two columns:

```
select coalesce(dist_admin, dist_user);
```

So your update should be like:

```
update surveys set dist_sting = coalesce(NULLIF(dist_admin,'') , NULLIF(dist_user,'') )
 FROM survey_ids  WHERE  surveys.id = survey_ids.id;
```

Comment: What about updating the dist_string with the coalesce?

Comment: Okay, when I do that, I notice my surveys table populates dist_string with only dist_admin in the places where dist_admin record has been populated. Why could that be?

Comment: That means that the column dist_admin is never NULL ? Is it an empty string instead ?